# Instagram API: Retrieve IDs/names of friends who have liked the user's posted Instagram images

Tags: javascript, html, instagram, instagram-api

We’re building an application where a user logs with Instagram API, accepts the permissions dialog and receives a personalised ‘dynamic story’ based on various data they allow us to read.

We’re hoping to display the user’s ‘top friends’ who have liked images that the user has posted onto their Instagram feed. Is there any way we could go about doing this?

Many thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Use this API to get all your followers:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Use this API to all your posts:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

For media_id's you get from the above API call, you can use this API to get the list users who have liked a media:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Compare the list of liker and list of followers to find the list of followers who have liked the media.

Note that Instagram only give the latest 120 likers in the API response, so if you photo gets more that 120 likes, you may not be able to efficiently get the data you want.

You also need `basic` and `public_content` API permissions to get the response from the APIs

Comment: Getting 404 page not found error against the likes API. Although I am able to get the post details via this open API though - `https://www.instagram.com/p/<post ID>/ ?__a=1` (which means post Id is working) and also able to get self details using the https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN API, which means my token is correct.

Comment: Okay, likes and followed-by were depecrated - https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/