# How to get usernames who have liked me on instagram by Instagram Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I have founded same issue [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326587/instagram-api-retrieve-ids-names-of-friends-who-have-liked-the-users-posted-in), but It's for 3 years ago and I'm sure that **Instagram Graph API** has been changed, so if someone tell me how can I **retrieve my user likers** for special post on my instagram acc, I'll appreciate it.

In addition, I need to retrieve usernames/IDs who have **shared**, **saved** or **commented** on my **special post**, too.

I have checked [these refrences](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/), but there weren't anything about these features, so could I use nodes and edges which has been introduced in **Graph API** docs for Instagram Graph API??

Comment: A lot changed since then. Now you have to use unofficial libraries to do that.

Comment: tnx Ali, Can you share some of them??

Comment: for what you want I think this best you can use: https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper. It works based on Instagram web and I used it for knowing who likes my post.

Comment: do you know could it retrieve users who share or save our posts or not?

Comment: No, you can not. at least with this library.